# Completely load web page in Javascript/Jquery without the need to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a plugin for an existing website whose code can not be changed. This website has a page that does not load fully but gradually as a result of scrolling to the bottom of it.

I can not add a plugin code to this page because this page is not fully built as long as I have not scrolled it.
My question is- How can I force this page to fully load immediately after it comes up without the need to scroll down?
thanks :)

Edit:

Before scrolling

[image]

After scrolling:

[image]

you can see the  tags loaded and are now  tags with the proper information.

My plugin is intended to go over the  properties and change the names.

Comment: _not load fully but gradually as a result of scrolling_ seems you are using infinite-scroll

Comment: sort of impossible to answer

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the load scroll behaviour?

Comment: What is the plugin mechanism that you have in mind for influencing its behavior: a Browser Extension, a clientside script (a la GreaseMonkey/Tampermonkey). or something other?

Comment: Just find out which event causes the loading on-scroll and trigger it manually?

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll down, is it the JavaScript/Jquery loading the new content? If so, seems like you have not choice but to change the *'website whose code can not be changed'* to load it completely first for you to continue what you need to do.

I suggest that you look at how the page is loaded first and post it here and we can suggest an approach that might have a lesser impact to the old code and negotiate it to the person that is prohibiting the change. :-)